# Prefer private static methods to instance methods

Tags: java, oop

I'm facing a strange situation. I'm actually trying JUnit testing for the first time. I've been taught for years that static methods aren't good (except in some cases).

BUT

I found really good to have some private static methods inside my classes. The main reason is that I can control everything that **goes inside** the method: I know for sure that I'll be able to control and change only the parameters.

Any example would be trivial, in fact it's only a method to "*prevent myself to do something wrong with the wrong object in the wrong situation*", maybe because I forgot that an object has to be the same from the beginning to the end of the execution of the method. Like encapsulation.

So, I'm explaining the last situation that made me think like this:

```java
class Graph {
   private Set<Edge> edges;

   // {...}

   public void newEdge(Edge e) {
      edges.add(e);
      edges = simplify(edges);
   }

   private static Set<Edge> simplify(Set<Edge> input) {
      // do something
      return output;
   }
}
```

Isn't this:

```java
private static Set<Edge> simplify(Set<Edge> input) {
   // do something
   return output;
}
```

safer than

```java
private void simplify(Set<Edge> input) {
   // do something
   this.edges = output;
}
```

?

Please, tell me if I'm mad. Thank you very much

Comment: static maybe safer but how are you setting `edges` from it?

Comment: Please check the first code sample, the method `newEdge` calls `simplify` and sets `edges` using the output of the static method

Comment: so they have different functionality - *hard* to compare... actually  both can be *dangerous*, the programmer may pass the wrong `Set` to `simplify`, maybe better have a non-`static` method without parameters. Very dependent of  context, what is being done, ...

Comment: Well, I think that this point of view is questionable. You could pass a wrong `Set` to `simplify`, but at the same time you could have tons of non-final objects that you could damage unconsciously.

Comment: From my end, I use static methods when I need to expose some piece of *self-contained* functionality. On the other hand, non static methods are useful when you need to expose a behaviour of the object.

Comment: The Java language probably doesn't have anything in it that isn't the best tool for *some* jobs.  Try to avoid thinking in terms of "this thing is better than that thing" generalizations.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that static methods aren't good, it's just that they have a specific purpose.

First of all, we're talking about a private method, so it's not usual for any code outside the class to be calling it. Therefore, only the developer of the class will be writing code to call it. This means it's less likely to be called incorrectly.

Also, your testing of the class should verify that it is performing the way it should.

Secondly, a static method has no access to the instance variables inside the object. So if the purpose of the method is to read from or modify an instance variable, then it can't be static.

If the calculation that the method is performing is common across an internal mutation of variables, and a public static method that wants to perform the same service for an external caller, then the method should be static. But if that's not the case, it doesn't need to be static.

**Edit**: For example:

If you have no external need to perform the simplification:

```
class Graph {
    private Set<Edge> edges;

    // {...}

    public void newEdge(Edge e) {
        edges.add(e);
        simplify();
    }

    private void simplify() {
        // use this.edges as your input
        // do something
        // set the value of your output to this.edges
    }
}
```

**Another edit**:

> an object has to be the same from the beginning to the end of the execution of the method

If consistency in a multi-threaded environment is an issue for you, you need to use the appropriate method of thread synchronisation - don't rely on only modifying an object at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Building further on my comment, as mentioned by @Jason, static methods aren't bad, it's just that there are some situations where they are more suited. For instance, exposing a piece of self contained functionality is usually what sets static methods apart.

This means that you will need to provide the arguments yourself, such as your `simplify` method. This does not really scale up, and if you have a `Graph` object, then, the `simplify` behaviour would be something that would be expected to be something that the object exposes.

This is were dependency injection comes into play, since it would make your tests easier to build. Thus, in your case, you would have something of the sort:

```
class Graph {
    private Set<Edge> edges;

    public Graph(Set<Edge> edges) {
        this.edges = ...
    }
}
```

Something such as the above would allow you to create a mock list of edges and then use that to perform your tests.